# Paginate update request?

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5

Good morning , I try to simplify my difficulty , however any extra doubt I will be available to provide any code information ...

I have a filter which which I do my research by certain values ​​and at the end have a paginate value:

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-label">
        {{Form::label('poder', 'Poder')}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        {{Form::select('poder', $poder, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-label">
        {{Form::label('unidade', 'Unidade')}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        {{Form::select('unidade', $unidade, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            {{Form::label('perPage', 'Deseja filtrar quantos resultados por página?', ['class' => 'pagilabel'])}}
            {{Form::number('perPage', null, ['class' => 'paginumber', 'min' => 0])}}
            {{Form::submit('Localizar', ['class' => 'btn btn-info'])}}
 </div>
```

In my controller have the Following:

```
    if ($request->poder) $query->where('orgao.poderId', $request->poder);
if ($request->unidade) $query->where('unid.id', $request->unidade);
$table = $query->paginate($request->perPage ? $request->perPage : 20);
```

Time to show the use of page like this:

```
<div class="text-center">{{$table->appends(['perPage' => $perPage])->links()}}</div>
```

Determined a default value of 20 results per page by paginate , everything works perfectly ....

My difficulty is ... : When I send filter a certain result , to change the page by paginate the request is canceled and shows all records of my respective table , as if my filter was canceled and the updated page.

My question is ... How do to send the same request made by the form every time you change the paginate page ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I use in the controller is the following, hope it works for you:

```
$paginator = $query->paginate($request->perPage ? $request->perPage : 20);
$table = $paginator->appends(Input::except('page'));
```

This makes sure the searched entities are kept